# Angularjs rest call example

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

```
!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="formmodule">
<body>
<form  method="get" ng-submit="submit()">
<div ng-controller="submitController">
Username :<input type="text" ng-model="uname"></br>
Password :<input type="password" ng-model="pwd"></br>
<button ng-click="submit()">submit</button>
 </div>
 </form>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.15/angular.min.js"></script>

<script>

var app=angular.module("formmodule",[]);

app.controller("submitController",function ($scope,$http) {

    $scope.submit = function () {

        var url = 'htttp://9.oo4.000.224:2020/restDemo/rest/user/'+$scope.uname+'/'+$scope.pwd;
        console.debug(url);


        $http.get(url).success(function (data) {
                     $scope.output = data;
                     Console.debug(data);
                     console.debug(output);

                });
```

My url is correct.Now my doubt is how to get response from server.Can any one help me.When i click submit button the rerquest gose to that url and validate my username and password.If my username and password is valide it will display my details.otherwirse it will display login failed information.

Comment: I realize you say your URL is correct, but it has lower case o's in it - are you absolutely sure that it's right?

Comment: yea and htttp? also, its not clear what exactly your question aims?